# How to connect to IoT Edge System Module using IoT Device SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-edge

I am aware that we can use IoT Device SDK to communicate with the modules in my IoT Edge device via module's connection string. I can connect to non-system edge modules, but not system modules. I would like to know if indeed this is not allowed, and if anyone knows any reference to it?

I am referring to the official sample in github.

Here's [c# sample for module](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/iot-hub/Samples/module).

```
ModuleClient moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(s_moduleConnectionString, s_transportType);

var sample = new TwinSample(moduleClient);
sample.RunSampleAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // this call the code below

//My breakpoint in RunSampleAsync()
//it hangs at the line below
Twin twin = await _moduleClient.GetTwinAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I expect it to behave the same for system module and non-system module. Non-system module works fine.

Comment: I don't understand the question; can you provide more details? A module deployed to an edge device can use the device SDK to communicate through Edge Hub to another module (send events, or invoke a direct method). Is this what you're trying to do?
Also, I'm confused about what you're trying to do with system vs. non-system modules. If you write a module and deploy it to your device, that's a non-system module. The system modules are `$edgeAgent` and `$edgeHub`. Is your module trying to send events to a system module? Or invoke a direct method on a system module?

Comment: @DamonBarry i need to build a library using device SDK to communicate with IoT edge device, which does not reside in the custom module. Through reading the documentations, i understand that $edgehub stores local cache. I would like to know if i can access the local cache or other properties as such in $edgehub. E.g. my custom module i can get module client object, then read their properties. Is there ways to do to connect to System module, and get their module clients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code that is deployed as a module to a device running IoT Edge. Your module can query its own twin and properties. The system modules that comprise the edge runtime (`$edgeAgent` and `$edgeHub`) can do the same for themselves. You should not try to connect to IoT Hub using the identity of one of the system modules because it would conflict with the system modules.

You can see any module's twin in the Azure portal, including system module twins. You can also use the [service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks#azure-iot-hub-service-sdks) with a shared access policy to get this information. (The RegistryManager sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/iot-hub/Samples/service) demonstrates connecting to IoT Hub to get twin info. It only shows devices not modules, but the concepts are similar.)

The Edge Hub (aka `$edgeHub`) does have a local cache where it temporarily keeps received messages until it can deliver them to other modules, or to the cloud. There is no public interface to this cache--it's completely internal and the format of the data stored there is subject to change at any time, so you shouldn't try to access it.

Comment: Thanks, your third paragraph answered my queries.